# While running this program I am not getting any response in web browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and while trying to run this code in Notepad++ latest version.
Nothing is loading into the browser. Is this a problem with my browser or code?
How would I modify this code to get output?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript">
Document.write("Hello Am Midhun");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. Try using a lower case 'd' in document ie. "document.write("Hello Am Midhun");"

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/tp8hcjy7/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Hello Am Midhun");
</script>
```

Comment: No problem, anytime :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use lowercase letter as `document.write("Hello Am Midhun");`